# Computational complexity of fractions multiplication puzzle

Tags: computational-complexity, puzzle

I developed a puzzle for which I am seeking an EFFICIENT algorithm (I searched Google but did not find this puzzle in the literature, ):

You have $k$ rationals, $n_1/d_1, n_2/d_2, ..., n_k/d_k$.

Query: Is there a way to flip some fractions and get 1 when multiplying all $k$ rationals $\prod_{i=1}^{k} n_i/d_i=1$ (flip turns a rational  upside down).

Here is a solvable instance: 243/16, 81/32, 27/162, 8/54, 432/128, 648/36

> Is there an efficient algorithm? or Is it NP-complete?

Comment: How is this different from subset sum or partition? Isn't there an easy reduction? Gerhard "Just Use Many More Fractions" Paseman, 2019.01.10.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman I do not see an easy reduction. Please post your answer.

Comment: Take an integer vector (or multiset) with sum of components 2N. Reduce to your problem by sending component  t to (2/3)^t.  Gerhard "This Is A Simple Reduction" Paseman, 2019.01.10.

Comment: The solution to the given instance is to flip the 1st, 4th, and the 5th fractions.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman You are not dealing with flipping operation!

Comment: I see flipping as turning t to -t. I believe subset sum (finding a subset of the vector so that the subset sums to N) is equivalent to this, and that the reduction preserves the problem hardness.  Gerhard "Yes, I'm Dealing With It" Paseman, 2019.01.10.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman But aren't you producing an exponentially larger instance?

Comment: Only if you take the representation of expanding it out. If you keep it in exponent form there is no expansion.  For your problem, you could do a similar reduction, and find that the size of the largest exponent and the number of terms determine a running time.  If that bothers you, then consider my version of your puzzle where the n's and d's are given by their prime factorization.  My version is at least as hard as subset sum. What does that make your version?  Gerhard "My Guess Is Even Harder" Paseman, 2019.01.10.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman The input to my puzzle is not in exponent form.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman My guess is that it is strongly NP-complete.

Comment: Integer factorization is strongly believed not to be NP-complete

Comment: @BenBurns I suggest that my puzzle is strongly NP-complete (not Integer factorization ).

Comment: It may be worth examining the simple version of your puzzle where all n's are powers of two and all d's are 1.  The pseudo-polynomial solution of subset sum might become polynomial for you.  Gerhard "Prefers Working The Easy Cases" Paseman, 2019.01.10.